# How to change keyboard shortcuts for copy, cut and paste and set keyboard shortcut for debugger (GDB)?

Tags: commands, keyboard-macros

I would like to set the following keyboard shortcuts:

- Copy (selected text): `C-c`
- Cut (selected text): `C-x`
- Paste from clipboard: `C-v`
- Debugger (GDB): `M-g`

Now I realize that to do this I merely need the command for each of these, and add lines of the form:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "shortcut") 'command)
```

to my `~/.emacs` file. The problem is that Googling emacs commands hasn't revealed the emacs commands for each of these. So all I need is the commands for each of these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `kill-ring-save` for `C-c`
- `kill-region` for `C-x`
- `yank` for `C-v`
- `gdb` for `M-g`

You should also look into enabling `cua-mode`, which ships with Emacs by default and allows usage of common keyboard shortcuts as expected with minimal setup. You can also use `C-h k` to see what a keybinding does and `C-h f` to see what a particular function does and what it's bound to currently.

Comment: I have set `kill-ring-save` to `C-c` but when I press `C-c` in Emacs it doesn't copy highlighted text. I only tried using this .emacs snippet because Cua mode doesn't seem to do this for me.

Comment: @BrentonHorne Hmm, I hadn't actually tried these solutions till now, but I had the same problem as you wrt `C-c` not working for copying. This happened both with enabling `cua-mode` and with running `(global-set-key (kbd "C-c") 'kill-ring-save)`. I suspect that this is happening b/c there are other keybindings to which `C-c` is already bound to, but as a prefix. You might want to try unbinding all other bindings to `C-c` and then see if it works correctly for copying regions.